# How to get line of code to accept single quote

Tags: php, javascript

Because of a single quote I am receiving a expecting ) after argument list error:

```
window.top.stopAudioUpload(1, '43', 'Thorne, Grandma's Goodbye excerpt.m4a');

audioupload.php (line 11, col 54)
```

My question is how can I get the line of code to accept single quote?

Code:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 window.top.stopAudioUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>, '<?php echo $id; ?>', '<?php echo $_FILES['fileAudio']['name'] ?>');
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes? like: `"<?php echo $_FILES['fileAudio']['name'] ?>"`

Comment: @darkajax Then what if the name contains a double-quote?

Comment: @Kolink Good point, and I upvoted your answer because it makes sense indeed, however it depends on the type of info, and considering the field is a file name I think it's unlikely it'll contain double quotes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
top.stopAudioUpload(
  <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>,
  <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>,
  <?php echo json_encode($_FILES['fileAudio']['name']); ?>
);
</script>
```

Note the lack of quotes - this is important, because `json_encode` will add these automatically if needed.

Comment: @VisioN Huh? What're you talking about? `json_encode` is THE way to put PHP variables into a JavaScript context, be it strings, ints, floats, arrays, even objects.

Comment: Ah, yeah, my bad. Forgot that `json_encode` doesn't always return string.

Comment: Say what? `string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 ] )` The whole point is for `json_encode` to return JSON, which is a string representing an object...

Comment: @Kolink Perfect, learned something bout json_encode, thanks :)

Comment: @Kolink This is what confused me: http://codepad.org/GrykoiJs. Hence, if it *really* always returns string, then my first (removed) comment was correct: *If only `$result` is expected to be string*: in the OP's code the first argument of `stopAudioUpload` is integer, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try \ escape character
'Thorne, Grandma\'s Goodbye excerpt.m4a'

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually escape your single-quote with a backslash `Thorn, Grandma\'s Goodbye excerpt.m4a` or you could use the escape function - see the docs here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Why on earth are you suggesting a MySQL function be used to put a string in JavaScript?

Comment: @WolfmanJoe `htmlspecialchars` won't escape single `'` quotes for you.

Comment: quoting the documentation:  `"'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is set. `

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies here:

`window.top.stopAudioUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>, '<?php echo $id; ?>', '<?php echo $_FILES['fileAudio']['name'] ?>');`

Changing the single quotes around`'<?php echo` will fix it.  So:

`window.top.stopAudioUpload("<?php echo $result; ?>", "<?php echo $id; ?>", "<?php echo $_FILES['fileAudio']['name'] ?>");`

You can also use `json_encode($_FILES['fileAudio']['name'])`.  This adds quotes automatically.

Comment: You can't just say "your issue lies here" and then quote the entirity of the code from the question...

Comment: I clearly called out the single quotes as the issue right here `'<?php echo`.  What's the problem with that?